# How to make a curl request from this data

Tags: php, curl, paypal

As I need to use paypal payout in my project. This is what I got from the official paypal page.https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '{
  "sender_batch_header": {
  "sender_batch_id": "2014021801",
  "email_subject": "You have a payout!"
  },
  "items": [
  {
    "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
    "amount": {
    "value": "9.87",
    "currency": "USD"
    },
    "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
    "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
    "receiver": "anybody01@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "recipient_type": "PHONE",
    "amount": {
    "value": "112.34",
    "currency": "EUR"
    },
    "note": "Thanks for your support!",
    "sender_item_id": "201403140002",
    "receiver": "91-734-234-1234"
  },
  {
    "recipient_type": "PHONE",
    "amount": {
    "value": "5.32",
    "currency": "USD"
    },
    "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
    "sender_item_id": "201403140003",
    "receiver": "408-234-1234"
  },
  {
    "recipient_type": "PHONE",
    "amount": {
    "value": "5.32",
    "currency": "USD"
    },
    "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
    "sender_item_id": "201403140004",
    "receiver": "408-234-1234"
  }
  ]
}'
```

and from this  I was able to make this in php.

```
$ch = curl_init();
        $header_object = (object) array('sender_batch_header'=>(object) array('sender_batch_id'=>"2014021801",'email_subject'=>"you got that"));
        $data_array = array('items'=>array(
    "recipient_type"=>"EMAIL",'amount'=>array('value'=>'9.87','CAD'),'note'=>'get your money',"sender_item_id"=>"232211",'receiver'=>"prabhs36@gmail.com"));
        $data = array($header_object,$data_array);
        // print_r($object);
        // die();
        $c_header =  ['Content-Type'=>'application/json"',
        'Authorization'=>'Bearer access_token_string_was_here'];
        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$c_header);
        // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, $data);

        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        $data_2 = curl_exec($ch);

        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);
```

I actually can't understand what is -d here means so what i could understand ,or i think it is , the `$data` variable is what i made. but I am getting the error that object of class std class cannot be converted to string. and array to string conversion.
Can anybody actually tell me that what is wrong and what should be done instead.

Comment: std class is the response that you are getting.When you are getting error on this ,problem would be handling the response

Answer (score 1):

`-d` means `data`, see https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d

You should encode data to JSON using `json_encode` and put it into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option

```
$data = ['name' => 'Alice', 'age' => '25'];
$dataStr = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataStr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($dataStr)
]);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

**UPDATE**

To have your data encoded, just put it into array like that:

```
$data = [
    'sender_batch_header' => [
        'sender_batch_id' => '2014021801',
        'email_subject' => 'You have a payout!',
    ],
    'items' => [
        [
            'recipient_type' => 'email',
            // ...
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];
```

**UPDATE2**

Consider using some HTTP client like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/). It provides clean and simple interface for making HTTP requests. Example for your case:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$data = [
    'sender_batch_header' => [
        'sender_batch_id' => '2014021801',
        'email_subject' => 'You have a payout!',
    ],
    'items' => [
        [
            'recipient_type' => 'email',
            // ...
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];

$res = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer Access-Token',
    ],
    'json' => $data,
]);

echo $res->getStatusCode();
// "200"
echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// {"batch_header":{"sender_batch_header"...
```

Comment: So I just have to json encode the data. but can you confirm that my $data is exactly like it its mentioned or not

Comment: $data =  (object)[
    'sender_batch_header' => [
        'sender_batch_id' => '2014021801',
        'email_subject' => 'You have a payout!',
    ],
    'items' => [
       (object) [
            'recipient_type' => 'email',
            // ...
        ],
        // ...
    ],
];

Comment: this is the format according to what i can seen up there. but still missing something . getting no response

Comment: It's possibly `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option (don't see it in your code)

Comment: yeah i removed it and still i am getting blank. can you go to that url and check what actually need to be done there

Comment: Not remove, add

Comment: It was there even then I was getting a blank. I added it now still getting blank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146024/discussion-between-sergey-kasatkin-and-prabhjot).